# How to transform flat JavaScript objects array into nested hierarchical JSON structure?

Tags: javascript

I need to transform the following flat JavaScript objects array:

```
[ [ { "name": "child1" }, { "name": "parent1" }, { "name": "grandparent1" } ], [ { "name": "child2" }, { "name": "parent2" }, { "name": "grandparent2" } ] ]
```

Into the following nested hierarchical JSON structure:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "child1",
            "parent": {
                "name": "parent1",
                "parent": {
                    "name": "grandparent1",
                    "parent": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "child2",
            "parent": {
                "name": "parent2",
                "parent": {
                    "name": "grandparent2",
                    "parent": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I accomplish this in JavaScript?

Comment: By writing code and showing us what you've tried first. You can easily do it with simple looping and/or Array prototype methods like `reduce` (or others)

Comment: If the schema of the arrays are always the same, it's not very complicated

Comment: What exactly is `{child1, parent1, grandparent1}`? Please post the input in proper JSON as you did with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I figured out the following solution, which seems to be working fine.

```
var familiesArr = [ [ { "name": "child1" }, { "name": "parent1" }, { "name": "grandparent1" } ], [ { "name": "child2" }, { "name": "parent2" }, { "name": "grandparent2" } ] ];
var hierarchicalFamilies = createHierarchicalFamilies(familiesArr);

function createHierarchicalFamilies(familiesArr) {
    var familyHierarchy = new Array();        
    for (var i=0; i<familiesArr.length; i++) {
        var family = familiesArr[i];
        familyHierarchy.push(addFamilyMember(family.slice()));
    }
    return familyHierarchy;
}

function addFamilyMember(family) {
    if (family.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    var familyMemberNode = family[0];
    var familyMember = new Object();
    familyMember.name = familyMemberNode.name;
    familyMember.parent = addFamilyMember(family.slice(1));
    return familyMember;
}
```